# How to disable all elements within a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div and when a checkbox is clicked I want to disable all the elements inside the div, including disabling the onClick of one of the elements. Here is the codepen:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVwMOq

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" onChange="checkMe(this)">
<div id="test">
  <input type="text">
   <span class="test">
    <img id="like" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/game-interface-outline/100/objects-15-512.png" height="40px" onclick="likeMe()">
   </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function checkMe(element){
  if($(element).prop('checked') === true){
    $('#test').prop('disabled', true).off("click");
  }
  else{
    $('#test').prop('disabled', false).on("click");
  }
}
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: `input[type=checkbox]:checked + #test { pointer-events: none; }`?

Comment: It would be easier to just add an invisible overlay, if say you have different onclick handlers on each item in the div

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, disabled with CSS.
you can't add disabled on div, it's working with input, etc..

```js
$('#clickCheckbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('#test').addClass('disable-button');
    }else{
      $('#test').removeClass('disable-button')
    }
    $('#clickCheckbox').val($(this).is(':checked'));        
});
```

```css
.disable-button {
   pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="clickCheckbox">
<div id="test">
  <input type="text">
   <span class="test">
    <img id="like" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/game-interface-outline/100/objects-15-512.png" height="40px" onclick="likeMe()">
   </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution below.
I have added in an additional input field to check it works on multiple items.

I created an checking function to see if your item is checked.

```
const isChecked = (element) => document.getElementById(element.id).checked ? true : false
```

Then updated the likeMe function to pass in the current id and returned null if the checkbox is checked.

```
function likeMe(element) {
    if (isChecked(element)) {
        return null
    } else {
        console.log('Calling likeMe()');
    }
}
```

Then I updated your checkMe function to pass in the current element and the targetdiv so this would be more reusable across other parts of your code.

```
function checkMe(element, targetDiv) {
    const targetDivInput = `#${targetDiv} input`
    const targetDivClassName = `.${targetDiv}`
    if (isChecked(element)) {
        $(targetDivInput).prop('disabled', true);
        $(targetDivClassName).toggleClass('disabled')
    } else {
        $(targetDivInput).prop('disabled', false);
        $(targetDivClassName).toggleClass('disabled')
  }
}
```

Then made some small changes to the markup to pass in the ids into your functions

```
<div id="test">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<span class="test">
<img id="like" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/game-interface-outline/100/objects-15-512.png" height="40px" onclick="likeMe('test')">
</span>
</div>
```

and added a disabled state to your css so the user wouldn't see the cursor.

```
#like{
    cursor: pointer;
}
.disabled #like {
    cursor: inherit;
}
```

This is the final result.

```css
    #like{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .disabled #like {
        cursor: inherit;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

const isChecked = (element) => document.getElementById(element.id).checked ? true : false

function likeMe(element) {
  if (isChecked(element)) {
    return null
  } else {
    console.log('Calling likeMe()');
  }
}

function checkMe(element, targetDiv) {
  const targetDivInput = `#${targetDiv} input`
  const targetDivClassName = `.${targetDiv}`
  if (isChecked(element)) {
    $(targetDivInput).prop('disabled', true);
    $(targetDivClassName).toggleClass('disabled')
  } else {
    $(targetDivInput).prop('disabled', false);
    $(targetDivClassName).toggleClass('disabled')
  }
}

</script>
    <input id="textCheck" type="checkbox" onChange="checkMe(this,'test')">

    <div id="test">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <span class="test">
    <img id="like" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/game-interface-outline/100/objects-15-512.png" height="40px" onclick="likeMe('test')">
    </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your checking function doesn't need to use a ternary, the `element.checked` will itself return a Boolean `true`/`false`; which allows you to use only: `const isChecked = (element) => document.getElementById(element.id).checked;`